# Does anybody know a good documentation that compares different Scheme implementations?

Tags: documentation, lisp, scheme, implementation

I am looking for a comparison of Chicken, SISC, Guile *etc*.  I tried to compare them by myself, but I'm wondering whether something about it already exists.

Comment: What aspects would you like to compare? Standards compilance? Standard library? Interoperability? Performance?

Comment: I do not know any good comparison site between Scheme implementations, but i switched from Guile to Chicken Scheme. The main reason was performance. It's great.

Comment: Performance and memory limits mainly. In my tests, I had very nice limits and performance with SISC. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: this seems to be a relatively broad comparison: [The Schemes I have Seen](http://www.aracnet.com/~briand/scheme_eval.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a table that shows the implementation status of various defined features across a series of Scheme implementations: http://web.mit.edu/~axch/www/scheme/choices.html

Comment: A tad only that one :) IIRC there is a newer version (on scheme.dk maybe?).